# Redirect in htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect

I want redirect to `print-salon.loc/land/badges/?city=moscow` when I on `print-salon.loc/land/badges/city-moscow` and I try use this code:

```
# BEGIN WPSuperCache
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^land/badges/city-([a-zA-Z]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /land/badges/index.php?city=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
# END WPSuperCache
```

but redirect does not happening.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, hope this one will be helpful. You can test the below added lines [here](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)

**Problems:**

> **1.** You skipped `/` in `REQUEST_URI` matching
>
> **2.** You should use `%1` instead of `$1`
>
> **3.** You should use `R` flag for redirection.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/land/badges/city-([a-zA-Z]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /land/badges/index.php?city=%1 [L,R]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've described the problem incorrectly, but here's the solution

```
RewriteRule ^land/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)/city-(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/land/$1/index.php?city=$2 [L]
```